# Create a sublist of fixed size from a list and if the elements are less add zeros to complete the sublist

Tags: java, list, generics, collections

I am new to Java 8 and trying the implement creating partitions of fixed size of 5 elements from a list.
If the list is short of elements then i need to add zeros to it.

For example: If the original list has below elements:
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

The sublist will be as below:
[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,0,0,0]

So far, i found the below method.
Can someone please help me with changing this to add zeros if a sublist is less than 5?

```
public static <T> List<List<T>> splitLists(List<T> alist, final int len) {
    return IntStream.range(0, alist.size()) 
            .filter(i -> i % len == 0) 
            .boxed() 
            .map(i -> alist.subList(i, Math.min(i + len, alist.size()))) 
            .collect(Collectors.toList()); 
}
```

Also, i need to pass a list of BigDecimal to this method,but want to keep this a generic list only so that i can reuse this method in other scenarios as well.

```
List<BigDecimal> l = new ArrayList<>();
l.add(new BigDecimal(1));
l.add(new BigDecimal(2));
l.add(new BigDecimal(3));
l.add(new BigDecimal(4));
l.add(new BigDecimal(5));
l.add(new BigDecimal(6));
l.add(new BigDecimal(7));
List<List<BigDecimal>> findPattern = splitLists(l,5);
```

Comment: I tested this code with a list of 12 elements. Below is the output that i am getting.   [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12] -- sublist [1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12] but i want the output as sublist [1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,0,0,0]

Comment: In your `splitList`, check the size of the last `List`. If the last less size is less than 5 add the right about of zeros.

Comment: can you please give an example cause when i am trying to do that, it is not accepting bigdecimal list anymore... i want to keep the method as generic list only so if something can be done within this code, will be helpful

Comment: Don't see how you get zeros without make `T` into `BigDecimal`. Given that if you pass an object zero would be invalid.

Comment: Right now this code works even if i pass a list of Bigdecimal to it, so if i can modify this code, i am hoping it will work

Comment: @Sedrick doable with reflection.

Comment: This question as posted defeats the purpose of `Generics`. Once you restrict it to only add zeros, it's no longer really a `Generic` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the question after answers were postet is a bad habit. However, BigDecimal, here we go:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal

List<BigDecimal> l = new ArrayList<>();
l.add(new BigDecimal(1));
l.add(new BigDecimal(2));
l.add(new BigDecimal(3));
l.add(new BigDecimal(4));
l.add(new BigDecimal(5));
l.add(new BigDecimal(6));
l.add(new BigDecimal(7));

List<List<BigDecimal>> findPattern = splitLists(l, 5, new BigDecimal (0));
```

We calculate the length mismatch and add a neutral element. Of course we need to get one of type T:

```
    int mismatch = len - (alist.size () % len);
    for (int i = 0; i < mismatch; ++i) 
         alist.add (neutral);


public static <T> List<List<T>> splitLists (final List<T> alist, final int len, T neutral) {
    int mismatch = len - (alist.size () % len);
    for (int i = 0; i < mismatch; ++i) alist.add (neutral) ;
    return IntStream.range(0, alist.size()) 
            .filter(i -> i % len == 0) 
            .boxed() 
            .map(i -> alist.subList(i, Math.min(i + len, alist.size()))) 
            .collect(Collectors.toList()); 
}
```

Call to that list expects one more parameter, the neutral element:

```
-> List<List<BigDecimal>> findPattern = splitLists(l, 5, new BigDecimal (0));
|  Modified variable findPattern of type List<List<BigDecimal>> with initial value [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 0, 0, 0]]
|    Update overwrote variable findPattern
```

(Testet in jshell, if you wonder about the fancy output.)

If you need your old List untouched, either pass a copy or create a copy in the method to work on.

Comment: mutating the original list is probably not expected of a function that returns a new list, maybe copy to a new List first?

Comment: @rpg711: Wasn't a requirement. Problem of the caller, to provide a copy. Or change the method, and make a copy. However, that's not the scope of the question, but orthogonal to it. :) If you need to, make a copy. An alternative would be, to heal the output of the original function.

Comment: the solution is not working. Please note that i need to pass a list of bigdecimal here

Comment: @user3378550: If you change the question, no wonder the solution doesn't work. It works for me, tested in jshell. What error do you get?